# C# Server - Client App on Different Computers

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, telnet

I'am writed Socket Server app using C#. When running this app on the same computer with windows telnet client, running succesfull. But when i running this app on different computers on the same network using telnet client, server-client comminication not providing.

Do I need open port on modem?

On the same computer => C# Server app + telnet client => Running successful.
On the different computers on the same network => 1. Computer Server + 2. Computer Client => Not working.

Comment: It also may be Windows Firewall blocking incoming connections when you running your server at computer other than yours.

Comment: Define "not working".  How specifically does it fail?  Can the client connect to the server on the specified port at all?

Comment: Client app not connecting Server :)

Comment: I'am deactived Windows Firewall. But Client App not connecting Server again. @AndyKorneyev

Comment: How is the server binding ? Is it somehow binding to localhost address maybe ? If it is, it will only listen to the loopback connection. If you want it to listen on every network addresses you have to bind it only on the port.

Comment: Server address = 127.0.0.1 port = 4xxx What do i need? Most apps do not require port forwarding on the same network. Am I not run without? (Sorry for my bad English.) @Hybris95

Comment: Just remove the Server address, binding on 127.0.0.1 means you only listen to loopback connection. If your library forces you to specify an address, specify "0.0.0.0" which means "Any Address" or you can try to specify your network card address (for example : 192.168.1.2) that way your socket will be binded on the proper network card.

Comment: I'm changed ip address to "192.168.1.4". But when i starting C# server app, getting this error http://prntscr.com/5eke0a @Hybris95

Comment: Catch the exception. Let us know what the value of SocketException.ErrorCode property is. Use the SocketException.ErrorCode property to obtain the specific error code. When you have obtained this code, you can refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in MSDN for a detailed description of the error.

Comment: Thank you for helps. I'm changed ip to IpAdress.Any, and solved problem :)

Answer (score 0):

when you create the socket

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 8888);
```

or local address
instead of

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
```

otherwise it works only locally